# Matlab: Integer linear progamm with nonzero constraint

Tags: matlab, integer, constraints, linear-programming

So I have to solve the following problem:

[image: problem]

I want to know how to solve this problem with Matlab's `intlinprog`. If I had *"less than or equal to"* instead of *"not equal to"* it would be trivial to solve.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Introduce a new integer variable (`sign`?) having possible values of `{-1, +1}` and then `sign * A * x > 0` ?  But that still leaves you with an inequality, so the next step is to replace `> 0` by `>= eps`

Comment: This makes the constraint nonlinear, so you can not solve it with intlinprog.

Comment: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html

Comment: [This resource](https://www.fico.com/en/resource-download-file/3217) taken from [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491) at Operations Research.SE might be helpful in constructing logical disjunctions (**See Sec 2.9, page 7**).

Comment: Possible cross-site dupe: [How can not-equals be expressed as an inequality for a linear programming model](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37075/572874)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint

```
Ax <= 0
```

is trivial. However the constraint

```
Ax <> 0
```

is not that easy. We can rewrite this as

```
y = Ax
y(i) >= 0.0001
or
y(i) <= -0.0001
```

This formulation immediately shows this problem has become non-convex. We may need binary variables to help us. E.g.:

```
y = Ax
y(i) >= 0.0001 - 1000*b(i)
y(i) <= -0.0001 + 1000*(1-b(i))
b(i) in {0,1}
```

Here I assume that `-1000 <= Ax <= 1000`.